# SQL Server matching tables in two directions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have a database (SQL Server 2014, pending upgrade to 2019) with tables containing data for several apps (e.g. AV, remote management, etc.), showing what servers/workstations have the app installed (and other properties). The tables are populated by querying each app's API.

I have been asked to create a report whose output looks like this:

| Hostname | Customer | AccountId | InApp1 | App1LastSeen90+ | InApp2 | App2LastSeen90+ | InApp3 | App3LastSeen90+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1.customerA | CustomerA | 1 | True | False | False | False | True | True |
| server2.customerA | CustomerA | 1 | True | True | False | False | False | False |
| workstation1.customerA | CustomerA | 1 | True | True | True | True | True | True |
| server1.customerB | CustomerB | 45 | False | False | False | False | False | False |
| server2.customerB | CustomerB | 45 | False | False | False | False | False | False |
| workstation1.customerB | CustomerB | 45 | True | True | False | False | False | False |
| workstation2.customerB | CustomerB | 45 | True | False | False | False | True | False |
| server3.customerC | CustomerC | 60 | True | False | False | False | True | False |
| server4.customerC | CustomerC | 60 | True | False | True | False | True | False |
| server5.customerC | CustomerC | 60 | True | False | False | False | True | True |
| server3.customerD | CustomerD | 100 | True | True | False | False | True | True |
| workstation10.customerE | CustomerE | null | True | True | False | False | False | False |

I know how to take one table and combine it with the devices from another table, but I do not know how to compare in the other direction (and how to do it more than once).

The input tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE app1Site
(
    siteId int NOT NULL, 
    siteUid varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    siteName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    companyName varchar(50), 
    companyId varchar(50)
);

insert into app1Site(siteId, siteUid, siteName, companyName, companyId)
values
(160424, '00531e92-08a2-496c-b462-99c9b7a13f1c', 'companyA', 'companyA', '1')
,(80484, '00ab6f2a-8e1d-49c8-ac44-c4905150c46c', 'companyB', 'companyB', '45')
,(111761, '00c45e63-3852-4c12-95e3-a76ac892bd24', 'companyC', 'companyC', '60')
,(140554, '0116aa15-c747-4042-a3d0-5513711e6564', 'companyD', 'companyD', '100')
,(136190, '01f03fb2-4902-4be7-9c1c-d7c3efdb69be', 'companyE', '[empty]', '[empty]');


CREATE TABLE app1Device
(
    deviceUid varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    id int NOT NULL, 
    siteUid varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    siteName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    hostname varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    lastSeen datetime
);

insert into app1Device(deviceUid, id, siteUid, siteName, hostname, lastSeen)
values
('00077984-ffc5-65cc-a3e1-3ce521c4dac2', 1741031, '00531e92-08a2-496c-b462-99c9b7a13f1c', 'CustomerA', 'server1', '8/9/22 1:01 AM')
,('00080a4e-4480-a66c-ddc9-51719acd61a4', 3999502, '00531e92-08a2-496c-b462-99c9b7a13f1c', 'CustomerA', 'server2', '1/9/22 11:00 PM')
,('000ab363-ee24-1b39-3f09-890afd827abd', 1822900, '00531e92-08a2-496c-b462-99c9b7a13f1c', 'CustomerA', 'workstation1', '2/19/21 5:35 AM')
,('000b4ed1-6ddd-9cc7-99c4-5438e88d370b', 1586482, '00ab6f2a-8e1d-49c8-ac44-c4905150c46c', 'CustomerB', 'workstation1', '4/29/22 10:25 AM')
,('000d6794-4b85-fd9c-8142-6646e48b1dfe', 4256471, '00ab6f2a-8e1d-49c8-ac44-c4905150c46c', 'CustomerB', 'workstation2', '8/9/22 1:01 AM')
,('0021ffc5-6eae-75cd-e1ac-acccf58ec54e', 3075938, '00c45e63-3852-4c12-95e3-a76ac892bd24', 'CustomerC', 'server4', '8/9/22 1:01 AM')
,('0025f7eb-edb2-70fa-d2ec-a8eb384f6aa6', 4234225, '00c45e63-3852-4c12-95e3-a76ac892bd24', 'CustomerC', 'server5', '8/9/22 1:01 AM')
,('000329fc-277a-6bdf-b21e-0c74e8a141b4', 4406129, '0116aa15-c747-4042-a3d0-5513711e6564', 'CustomerD', 'server3', '10/5/21 3:53 PM')
,('001006af-20aa-6ba8-ca50-00fc08af6834', 4082779, '01f03fb2-4902-4be7-9c1c-d7c3efdb69be', 'CustomerE', 'server9', '8/9/22 1:01 AM')
,('001f96c1-99a2-8de9-453d-5d0dfaa2c589', 1341934, '01f03fb2-4902-4be7-9c1c-d7c3efdb69be', 'CustomerE', 'workstation10', '1/9/20 3:01 PM')


CREATE TABLE app2Group
(
    id varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    accountId int NOT NULL
);

insert into app2Group(id, name, accountId)
values
('24124b96-0910-48e9-88ee-6047d986d0a5','CustomerA',1)
,('7ef1b94a-0823-4c9f-b91b-03cb26a948bf','CustomerB',60)


CREATE TABLE app2Endpoint
(
    id varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    endpoint varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    [group] varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    lastSeenOnline datetime
);

insert into app2Endpoint(id, endpoint, [group], lastSeenOnline)
values
('{f7bd2eea-b172-49d8-9c81-fb79dba2252c}','workstation1','CustomerA','5/19/2022')
,('{f854999a-715e-4244-920c-3157ddd5f00d}','server4.customerC.local','CustomerC','8/9/2022')


CREATE TABLE app3Customer
(
     customerId varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

insert into app3Customer(customerId, name)
values
('2CF1F625-74E1-4FBE-AB63-8B2A5D268020', 'customerA')
,('49219DC1-3514-43C4-8A7D-A50CDA4B081D', 'customerB')
,('25E54580-7353-4173-943C-F020B91E3E50', 'customerC')
,('72F9A12E-3056-49FD-8913-FBB9E0E60755', 'customerD')


CREATE TABLE app3Computer
(
    customerId varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    id varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    last_connect_time int, 
    last_connect_time_human datetime
);

insert into app3Computer(customerId, id, name, last_connect_time, last_connect_time_human)
values
('2CF1F625-74E1-4FBE-AB63-8B2A5D268020','289cfdacfb0ca44d97f3a26cdd660a43','server1',1641752053,'1/9/22 6:14 PM')
,('2CF1F625-74E1-4FBE-AB63-8B2A5D268020','3525f3b38a085b49a2c83947b86a136e','workstation1',1641752070,'1/9/22 6:14 PM')
,('49219DC1-3514-43C4-8A7D-A50CDA4B081D','679b0049216e9043bc5c97e7d27a4089','workstation2',1660069094,'8/9/22 6:18 AM')
,('25E54580-7353-4173-943C-F020B91E3E50','dbdebabe8cdf64459d248afd348adc65','server3',1660069094,'8/9/22 6:18 AM')
,('25E54580-7353-4173-943C-F020B91E3E50','e27443e41067b84fb5c53c77c8b646e3','server4',1660069094,'8/9/22 6:18 AM')
,('25E54580-7353-4173-943C-F020B91E3E50','24e17f22b3996b42b16745711802dd68','server5',1650395673,'4/19/22 7:14 PM')
,('72F9A12E-3056-49FD-8913-FBB9E0E60755','c755daf89781034abfc738617467ce89','server3',1643699673,'2/1/22 7:14 AM')
```

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT
  a1d.hostname AS Hostname
  ,a1d.siteName AS Customer
  ,a1s.companyId AS AccountId
  ,CASE WHEN a1d.hostname IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS InApp1
  ,CASE WHEN a2e.endpoint IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS InApp2
  ,CASE WHEN a2e.lastSeenOnline > DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS App2LastSeen90
FROM [app1Device] a1d
LEFT JOIN [app1Site] a1s ON a1s.siteUid = a1d.siteUid
LEFT JOIN [app2Group] a2g ON CAST(a2g.accountId AS varchar(50)) = a1s.companyId
JOIN [app2Endpoint] a2e on a2e.[group] = a2g.[name] and a2e.endpoint like (a1d.hostname + '%')
```

For some reason, with the test data, I only get back one row. In production the device names are sometimes just the host name and are sometimes the FQDN (server4 vs. server4.customerC.local). When I ran the same query against prod, I got back about 18k rows, but I do not know how many devices are in each table.

If it is helpful, I also put all of this into db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f73075c1e91222256ede1ea932c12556

Given all of that, how would I most efficiently generate the requested output?

Comment: JOINs have no direction. What you posted doesn't look like a star schema, a typical schema used in data warehouses. Nor does it look like a reporting schema. These could be tables in an OLTP database except for the ... unusual ... prefixes app1, app2, app3. A data warehouse is supposed to make querying easier, not act as a read-only store for transactional data

Comment: `In production the device names are sometimes just the host name and are sometimes the FQDN (server4 vs. server4.customerC.local).` not in a data warehouse. A DW is supposed to contain cleaned data. Any cleaning, matching, denormalization, key generation should happen when loading the data, not when trying to query it

Comment: There are other huge problems too: `CAST(a2g.accountId AS varchar(50))` won't be able to use any indexes covering `accountid` and will have to scan the entire table to find matches. As for `a2e.endpoint like (a1d.hostname + '%')`, if you want to match endpoints with their devices, extract the domain *first* or even better, map the domain to device and use the DeviceID in the tables, not the host name

Comment: Okay, so I do not have a data warehouse, I have a series of tables in SQL, populated with data from the apps (retrieved via their APIs). I am not a DBA and do not have any control over the schema each app uses. Each app has its own name for a server/workstation. App1 uses the term, "devices". App2 uses the term "endpoints", and app3 uses the term, "computers". Given that, if you still suggest, "map the domain to device and use the DeviceID", then I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Your data is going to make anything difficult. Technically you can combine a `CASE` statement with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` to identify the hostname. You could then use a couple of unions to generate a distinct list across the three tables. Then start doing `LEFT JOIN` with the `CASE` statement again... It's possible if you have to, if you have any control over the database at all you might want to sanitize each app in it's own `VIEW` first making the joins simpler.